# Echoing more than one word to a file makes it crash. (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file, crash, words

So I am creating a Mail program in batch, and I am having a problem with the messaging part.
The messaging part is an endless loop-ish.
When I type more than one word it crashes.
This is the code.    PLEASE HELP!

```
:rep
set line=
set /p line=
if %line% == end set end= 1
if %line% == end echo. >>"\\FAMILY-PC\Users\Public\HailDatabase\HailMail\Accounts\%send%\%msgname%".MAIL
if %line% == end set line= From, %user%
echo %line% >>"\\FAMILY-PC\Users\Public\HailDatabase\HailMail\Accounts\%send%\%msgname%".MAIL
if %end% == 1 goto msgdone
goto rep
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around basically everything to preserve the spaces in `%line%`. Also, your `if` statements can **not** have spaces around the `==`, because batch will interpret those spaces to be part of the strings to compare and you will always get a false result.

```
:rep
set "line="
set /p "line="
if "%line%"=="end" set "end=1"
if "%line%"=="end" echo. >>"\\FAMILY-PC\Users\Public\HailDatabase\HailMail\Accounts\%send%\%msgname%.MAIL"
if "%line%"=="end" set "line= From, %user%"
echo %line% >>"\\FAMILY-PC\Users\Public\HailDatabase\HailMail\Accounts\%send%\%msgname%.MAIL"
if "%end%"=="1" goto msgdone
goto rep
```

Comment: @TheBeastprogrammer - Happy to help. If my answer worked for you, please click the check next to my answer to mark it as Accepted.